# Переклад "действующий абонент" українською мовою в рекламі

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Прошу допомоги з перекладом словосполучення "действующий абонент" українською мовою за умови, якщо він вживається в такому контексті: "новим абонентам пропонуємо знижку, а "действующим абонентам" - участь у розіграші". Як на мене, варіанти "теперішнім" або "наявним" абонентам для рекламного тексту не найкріщі, аудиторія до них не звикла. Думала над варіантом "постійні" абоненти, але чи зберігається тут те саме значення, що й у слові "действующий"? Дякую

Comment: Див. також: [«Переклад „действующий вулкан“ українською»](/q/2978), [«Чи правильно вживати слово „існуючий“?»](/q/3270) (я розумію, що там потрібної Вам відповіді, найімовірніше, все одно нема, просто намагаюся не загубити дещо пов'язані запитання).

Comment: А як щодо _давнім/старим_? Або завуальовано — _«…а нашим старим друзям — участь у розіграші»_.

Comment: Дякую. На жаль, потрібне саме слово абонент, хоча ідея з друзями також приваблива )))

Comment: Погоджуюсь із коментарем @Sasha до моєї відповіді. Тут варто обрати якійсь зворот, бо й російською розділення на *действующие" и "новьіе" якось не дуже.

Answer (score 3):

Мабуть, *чинний абонент*, але також можна *дійсний абонент*.

> *Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)*
> Действующий – ді́ючий, чи́нний, -а, -е.

Comment: Згідно з СУМ-11, _[чинні](http://sum.in.ua/s/chynnyj)_ має трішки недоречну конотацію (хоча СУМ-11 міг уже застаріти). А от _дійсні_, на мій погляд, могло б і підійти. Хоча щодо _дійсних_ є контраргумент: «А нові абоненти хіба недійсні (несправжні)? Вони ж теж дійсні». Проте: (1) те саме можна сказати й про російське _действительные_, однак його все-таки застосовують у такому контексті; (2) мабуть, мається на увазі «дійсні/действительные **[на момент початку акції]**».

Comment: @Sasha *недійсні* це також можуть бути такі, що тимчасово відключені за несплату, чи навіть повінстю відключені - *колишні абоненти*.

Answer (score 2):

У вашому констексті, як на мене, можна застосувати і "активний".

"Новим абонентам таке, а уже активним — сяке".

Answer (score 2):

**ІСНУЮЧИЙ АБОНЕНТ**

[ЗАКОН УКРАЇНИ «‎Про телекомунікації»](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/1280-15#Text)‎ в Загальних Положеннях надає визначення терміну:

*"**абонент** - **споживач телекомунікаційних послуг**, який отримує телекомунікаційні послуги **на умовах договору**, котрий передбачає підключення кінцевого обладнання, що перебуває в його власності або користуванні, до телекомунікаційної мережі"*

а Стаття 32 п.2 уточнює:

***Абонент**, який отримує телекомунікаційні послуги **без укладення договору в письмовій формі, може зареєструватися в оператора, надавши йому персональні дані** відповідно до закону в порядку, встановленому національною комісією, що здійснює державне регулювання у сфері зв’язку та інформатизації.*

[Словник заміни дієприкметникових форм](http://academy.gov.ua/NMKD/library_nadu/Biblioteka_Magistra/05d51485-7bad-43d2-a332-af203a10f6ec.pdf) українськими відповідниками пропонує наступні форми для заміни калькованого **"існуючий"** в діловому тексті:
[image: існуючий]

Тлумачення термінів "**абонент**", "**існуючий абонент**" і "**новий абонент**" також визначено "[Правилами користування мережею](https://www.vodafone.ua/terms-of-use)" окремих операторів та "Правилами проведення акцій":
 [(див. п.2.1 Існуючі абоненти Компанії, які обслуговуються на контрактній формі)](https://cdn.kyivstar.ua/sites/default/files/promotions/bez-abonplat/media/official_rules_bez-abonplat.pdf),
[(6.1.2. Існуючим абонентам, у яких є номер Vodafone Україна...)](https://www.vodafone.ua/storage/editor/files/507188promo-supernet-01072020.pdf)

**ІСНУЮЧИЙ АБОНЕНТ** — це такий користувач телекомунікаційних послуг, особу якого оператор зв'язку може ідентифікувати за зареєстрованими персональними даними.

Answer (score 1):

Якщо потрібна саме передача смислу, а не дослівний (буквальний) переклад, можна скористатися словом "стаж".

Новим абонентам пропонуємо знижку, абонентам зі стажем - участь у розіграші.

Плюс пропонованої конструкції - позитивне підкреслення ознаки.

Comment: Я не автор запитання, але мені особисто — дуже подобається.

Answer (score 0):

1. Новим абонентам пропонуємо знижку, а {старим/давнім} — участь у розіграші.
2. Новим абонентам пропонуємо знижку, а {вже підключеним / підключеним раніше} — участь у розіграші.

Comment: Цей допис сильно виграв би, якби містив посилання на джерела. Чи варто створювати відповіді, які потрапляють до "Low Quality Posts" Review Queue?

Comment: @Sasha, А чому не "чинним" (абонентам)?

Comment: @behemothus, я не проти інших варіантів, я просто навів ті, що спали мені на думку (а _чинні_ і _дійсні_ вже [Yola навів](/a/6417)). Окрім того, мені здається, у СУМ-11 [чинний](http://sum.in.ua/s/chynnyj) має трішки інший набір значень (це: (¹.1) щось офіційно-оридичне; (¹.2) діяльний; (²) статечний, гордий) — але він міг уже застаріти (або від початку неповну картину показувати, або я міг неправильно інтерпретувати).

Answer (score -1):

новим абонентам пропонуємо знижку, а дійсним - участь у розіграші

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].